# Flutter how to redirect to login if not authorized

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to redirect to login in case the token has been expired in Flutter

Trying to get the posts:

```dart
body: new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
    color: Color(0xff2c3e4e),
    child: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
        future: api.getposts(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            // doing stuff with response
        }
    )
)
```

getposts and catching the error:

```dart
Future<List<Post>> getposts() async {
    url = 'url';
    var response = await http.get(url,
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'bearer ' + token},
    );
    //part I can't understand how to get to work, how do I push? This gives error about context not being defined.
    if (response.body.toString().contains('Token is Expired')) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    LoginScreen()),
        );
    }
}
```

So the question is, how do I use the Navigator correctly in such cases and I can redirect back to loginScreen in case the token has been expired and needs to be renewed? Like mentioned in the comment in the code example, the context gives me "undefined".

Is this even possible the way I am doing it or am I simply handling the whole check completely wrong?

Comment: You can use redux to manage a global state, I have written a small application with splashScreen here: https://github.com/EdHuamani/flutter_redux_sample_1

Comment: Checking the content text for a string is highly likely to break in the future when some other string is returned. You're much better off checking for the HTTP status codes (exactly why they were designed) e.g. `if response.statusCode == 401...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code should have single resonpsibility. Your `getPost` method are doing 2 things at the same time. You should break this function such that it either successfully get the the post, or throw exception, and its caller will handle the exception. Its caller btw must be within `build` method, because only `build` method has `BuildContext context`, something like this:

```
      if (response.body.toString().contains('Token is Expired')) {
        throw new Exception("Token is Expired") // you may want to implement different exception class
      }
```

```
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
        color: Color(0xff2c3e4e),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
            future: api.getposts(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                // you might want to handle different exception, such as token expires, no network, server down, etc.
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
                );
                return Container(); // return empty widget
              }
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // do somthing with data
                return Text('Some data here');
              }
              // has no data
              return Text("Loading...");

            }),
      ),
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @TruongSinh I got it figured out.

Followed his example and figured out the build navigator method which works:

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {

              @override
              void run() {
                scheduleMicrotask(() {

                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
                  );
                });
              }
              run();
}
```

Comment: Error catching seems to work perfectly, thank you. However the Navigator's return gives me "error: Missing return value after 'return'. Tried without i t as well but then I'm getting an error: Failed assertion: line 1554 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.

Comment: hmm, maybe it always require a widget when return, did you try an empty Widget, such as `return Container();`?

Comment: Container unfortunately returned getter null, but I found that it has to be wrapped into scheduleMicrotask since the tree has not yet ran through. I did just that and got it to login page, however it loops indefinitely, doing the redirect multiple times in nevery second. Trying to find a proper documentation for the scheduleMicrotask and why it is acting like that at the moment.

Comment: Thank you once again. Got it figured out! Instead of .push I used .pushReplacement and wrapped it to void function which I then fired up.

Comment: I don't understand why we need so much logic in the view, this is ridiculus

Answer (score 5):

I did it with a `StreamBuilder` to react on change and be able to display a LoadingScreen when we don't know yet if the user is connected.

```
StreamBuilder authGuard = StreamBuilder(
  stream: Auth.authState$,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.data) {
      case AuthState.PENDING:
        return LoadingScreen();
      case AuthState.UNAUTHENTICATED:
        return SignInScreen();
      case AuthState.AUTHENTICATED:
        return HomeScreen();
      default:
        return LoadingScreen();
    }
  },
);
```

So it will change screen depending on the AuthState:

```
return MaterialApp(
  // ...
  home: authGuard,
);
```